# Intent for otg-cable

Tags: android, android-intent, usb-otg

I want to build an android app where in , i want to detect the otg-cable connection to the device.for eg. I want to display toast on such detection, is it possible? I mean is there any intent for the same?
Any help will be greatly appreciated 
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at the official Documentation for USB Host: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html#discovering-d